# Windows Subversion differences

Tags: windows, svn

In Unix it is easy to perform subversion differences. I have output all files to a directory and did a diff on each one of them.

However, in Windows, how can i do this without using tortoise SVN? I want to extract the files from subversion into a directory on local machine and compare them with the files i have received from a production machine and then do a diff.

I want to be able to write a script that i can run whenever i need to.

How can i achieve this on windows?

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as you would on *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN 1.7 and newer has an option to install the command-line client tools (`svn.exe`, etc.) which work identically to the UNIX versions. And you can get a Win32 Console version of `diff` from a [variety of sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=win32+diff) Then glue them together using your scripting tool of choice - WSH, PowerShell or BAT.

Some might also suggest using `Cygwin`; I really dislike the idea of attempting to emulate one OS's environment on another like that, as it doesn't always work the way you'd expect. But if you already have a shell script on UNIX, that may be the path of least resistance in porting it over to Windows.